# How to decode characters utf-8 in iso 8859-1 with json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, json, extjs

In php I select data and display in php with last code

```
utf8_decode(json_encode($resultat, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

and get this result : 
[ { "NUM_ASSU": "321-7777777-4", "NOM_ASSU": "MÀJIOTSOP TIAYA VALERIE" } ]
with correct data and accented characters.
but when I am back in Javascript coded with ExtJs framework it displays nothing.
this is the code:
`var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText, true);`
jsonData appears empty.

Comment: js will expect utf8, not iso

Comment: and generally, if you are going to use accented characters, stick to utf-8.

Comment: I use ExtJS 3.0 I usually put charset=ISO 8859-1 because When I stick with utf8, labels with accented characters appear with "?", meaning that ExtJS do not understand those one.

Answer (score 0):

Your server application has to communicate with the client in the correct encoding. The page encoding is set usually in page header, e.g.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250"/>
```

In this case you have to encode your server response in `windows-1250`. But I'd rather stick with `utf-8` as other people say.

You can check your current page encoding like this:

```
alert(document.characterSet);
```

Side note: can you inspect `result.responseText`?